# ms access negative page numbers

Tags: ms-access, reporting, paging

I have an access report that generates 36505 pages (**un** filtered, and about half of each page is taken up by group headers and page headers) , though the footer at the bottom of the report page says "36505 of -29031". This looks like an overflow problem maybe, though I'm confused how it got the current page number of the last page OK, but failed to get total page count. Has anyone dealt with this before?

Comment: I can't imagine a real use for a 36K-page report. Also, keep in mind that using PAGES increases the lag time between printing the report and when it will actually be sent to the printer, because it has to format the whole report before it can print the first page (assuming you got "Page & Page & " of " & Pages on all your pages).

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: I very much doubt anyone will try to print it (or use it any other way) unfiltered. Filtering (depending on the criteria) usually leaves the user with anything from 10 to 300 pages (and a good chunk of page-space is given over to headers and footers - and they could be made smaller but this is how they want it...). If they feel 300 is too much, they can just apply stricter filters. I was just curious why the # of pages count was so funky.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you change the report so that it can never print all the pages. The easiest way to do this is to use some sort of filtering mechanism. In thinking about my own apps that have 100s of thousands of records, none of the output is unfiltered, and the openended reports are opened via a data retrieval interface that allows complex querying of the database. Thus, there's never any possibility of *users* every opening the unfiltered report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a clue on this page:

http://www.sqldrill.com/excel/access-reports/695207-access-prints-negative-number.html

But the expression wasn't 100% so I had to modify it:

```
="Page " & [Page] & " of " & IIf([Pages]<1,(32768-Abs([Pages]))+32768,[Pages])
```

Page numbers appear to be correct now. :)

Comment: +1 Good sleuthing on that one.  Still I think my preferred solution would be a shorter report.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

In my Access 2003 report, this reports *Page* as Long and *Pages* as Integer.  (I assume your report has this as the footer text box expression: ="Page " & [Page] & " of " & [Pages])  So it makes sense you're getting an apparent overflow for *Pages* but not *Page*.

```
Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Debug.Print "TypeName(Me.Page) " & TypeName(Me.Page)
    Debug.Print "TypeName(Me.Pages) " & TypeName(Me.Pages)
End Sub
```

I don't know of a work-around.  I've never dealt with such a huge report.

Comment: That explains the problem. I guess it begs the next question: Why are they of different types when they represent the same kind of information?

Comment: No idea here, Frustrated.  I was surprised to see that.  Superficially at least it seems stupid to me.

Comment: Nice work.  And very interesting.   Almost certainly a holdover from Access 1.0 days on Win 3.1 and never been updated.   I can also see the discussions now "But nobody will ever print a report with more than 10,000 pages."

Comment: I think it's quite reasonable. If you have so many pages that it overflows the integer data type, your report is going to take a RILLY long time to calculate the value of Pages.